# device.uuid of the phonegap in ios gives which value

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Like in android device.uuid of phone gap gives the android_id . Similarly in ios the device.uuid of the phonegap gives which id.

Answer (score 0):

The UDID is no longer averrable on iOS. You can not get any hardware identifiers on iOS. This is no longer allowed by Apple.

As stated in the [documentation of PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html) the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) will be returned:

> **iOS Quirk**
>
> The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
>   application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
>   re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
>   upgrade the app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
>   reliable value.

Comment: Example in android device.uuid is giving ANDROID_ID value of the native similarly for ios device.uuid gives which value

Comment: Did you read you answer! It gives you the `identifierForVendor` just as stated int the documentation of PhoneGap.

Comment: It should according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

On cordova 3.7.0, for iOS it returns

```
- (NSString*)uniqueAppInstanceIdentifier
{
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    static NSString* UUID_KEY = @"CDVUUID";

    NSString* app_uuid = [userDefaults stringForKey:UUID_KEY];

    if (app_uuid == nil) {
        CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        CFStringRef uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidRef);

        app_uuid = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString*)uuidString];
        [userDefaults setObject:app_uuid forKey:UUID_KEY];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        CFRelease(uuidString);
        CFRelease(uuidRef);
    }

    return app_uuid;
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/index.html

on android it returns

```
    public String getUuid() {
        String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        return uuid;
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID